# i18n localization does not accept html tags in translation strings

Tags: angular, internationalization

I am using i18n to add localization to my angular app and I have run into an issue.  i18n does not seem to support html tags. It generates an error when I run I try to generate the localized bundles.

Here's an example:

```
<div i18n="@@termsOfUseDetail">
  
      <p> something <a href="https://www.test.com" target="_blank">www.test.com</a> (« Test »).
         something something something something something something something
      </p>
</div>
```

Here's the error:

There is a placeholder name mismatch with the translation provided for the message "termsOfUseDetail" ("{$START_PARAGRAPH} etc...

It works fine if the text has no html in it.

Any ideas?

Thanks for any insights